# How to remove space in after and before pseudo elements at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a section in which at the bottom, I have triangle shape, which i am doing with after and before elements and clip path. Below is the image of that section.

[image]

The problem is, on certain device width, it is leaving around 1px of space at the bottom and on certain width it is leaving same space from both the sides.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #424963;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.stats-section {
  background-color: #1B2235;
  padding: 200px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-triangle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bottom-triangle .triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ED0F0C;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  clip-path: polygon(0 120px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.bottom-triangle:after,
.bottom-triangle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50.05%;
  background-color: #424963;
  z-index: 9;
}

.bottom-triangle:after {
  right: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 70px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.bottom-triangle:before {
  left: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 70px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="stats-section clipped-top">
        <div class="bottom-triangle">
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-content">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
                                <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">30</h2>
                                <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Years in Business</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
                                <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">1330</h2>
                                <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Projects Completed</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
                                <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">330</h2>
                                <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Families Supported</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
                                <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">660</h2>
                                <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Jobs Created</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

I have tried few solutions and searched online, but couldn't find a a cause or solution. You can see a fine line at the bottom in the image or else below is the fiddle link where you can see the issue by resizing the browser window:

https://jsfiddle.net/vishal157/fj91n8tq/

How to achieve the same triangle with the section having background image and gradient overlay with the little shadow looming over? Like below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it differently with less of code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #424963!important;
}
.stats-section {
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,#ED0F0C 50%)
   bottom right/
   50% 150px  /* adjust the 150px to control the red triangle */
   no-repeat,
   #1B2235; /* you can replace the color with an image */
  padding: 100px 0 200px;
  /* adjust the 110px to control the main triangle */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 110px),50% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 110px));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<section class="stats-section clipped-top mb-5 text-white">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-content">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
                                <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">30</h2>
                                <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Years in Business</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
                                <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">1330</h2>
                                <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Projects Completed</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
                                <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">330</h2>
                                <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Families Supported</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
                                <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">660</h2>
                                <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Jobs Created</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Another idea more supported still with less of code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #424963!important;
}

.stats-section {
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  padding: 100px 0 200px;
}

.stats-section::before,
.stats-section::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: #1B2235;
}

.stats-section::before {
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: skewY(8deg);
}

.stats-section::after {
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: skewY(-8deg);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49.8%, #ED0F0C 50%) 
    bottom right/100% 50px 
    no-repeat #1B2235;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="stats-section clipped-top mb-5 text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-content">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">30</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Years in Business</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">1330</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Projects Completed</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">330</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Families Supported</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">660</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Jobs Created</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
```

And with image as background:

```css
body {
  background-color: #424963!important;
}

.stats-section {
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  padding: 100px 0 200px;
}

.stats-section > span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: #1B2235;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.stats-section > span::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/800/800) left/200% auto;
  transform-origin:inherit;
  transform: skewY(-8deg);
}
.stats-section > span:nth-of-type(2)::before {
  transform: skewY(8deg);
  background-position:right;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49.8%, #ED0F0C 50%) 
     bottom right/100% 10vw no-repeat,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/800/800) right/200% auto;
}
.stats-section > span:nth-of-type(1){
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: skewY(8deg);
}

.stats-section > span:nth-of-type(2) {
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: skewY(-8deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="stats-section clipped-top mb-5 text-white">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-content">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">30</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Years in Business</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">1330</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Projects Completed</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">330</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Families Supported</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">660</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Jobs Created</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, great solution. +1 for less code. one more question. Any alternatives for clip path? because IE doesn't support that.

Comment: @VishalBhatt check the update, added another solution

Comment: That was exactly i wanted. Thanks for the solution. However the same trick i tried for my hero section, but i guess that won't work with bg images. I have updated the question. Can you suggest any solution for that?

Comment: Hey, red part of the triangle is not displaying in large screens. And isn't it possible to take background image in section itself?

Comment: @VishalBhatt updated the red triangle, for the image, no you cannot use it in it's section alone using my solution ... I think you have to ask a new question because actually you are adding more requirement to your initial question and this is confusing and you won't get the help you want and you make other answer irrelevant. Your initial question didn't contain the use of background and the requirement of IE support

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I will accept this answer and ask new one for other confusions.

Comment: your all the solutions are working great. But somehow i have to stick to the code i have posted in the question. Can you provide solution for that that why it is leaving some space at the bottom? I have tried possibly everything i know but failed.

Comment: one strange thing i have noticed. I have absolute positioned element in that section. When i hide that or remove its position, that space at the bottom disappears. but example here has no elements that are absolute. Still that space is there.

Comment: @VishalBhatt try `bottom:-1px` instead of `bottom:0`

Comment: I tried that already. but with the screen size change it appears again. and when i use this code inside container, space also appears from the left and right side too.

Comment: @VishalBhatt remove the width:100% and try left:-1px right:-1px

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with only linear-gradients like below.

```css
.stats-section {
  background-color: #1B2235;
  padding: 100px 0 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  /* you can change these variables */
  --bottom-height: 100px;
  --arrow-height: 100px;
  --red-height: 150px;
  --c1: #424963;
  --c2: #ED0F0C;
  
  height: calc(var(--bottom-height) + var(--red-height));
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top left, var(--c1) 49.5%, transparent 50% 100%) 100% calc(100% - var(--bottom-height))/50% var(--arrow-height) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top left, var(--c2) 49.5%, transparent 50% 100%) 100% calc(100% - var(--bottom-height))/50% var(--red-height) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top right, var(--c1) 49.5%, transparent 50% 100%) 0 calc(100% - var(--bottom-height))/50% var(--arrow-height) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(var(--c1), var(--c1)) 0 100%/ 100% var(--bottom-height) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="stats-section text-white">
  <div class="bottom-triangle">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-content">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">30</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Years in Business</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">1330</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Projects Completed</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">330</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Families Supported</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-4 mt-xl-0 text-left text-xl-center">
              <h2 class="mb-0 stat-number">660</h2>
              <p class="mb-0 stat-desc font-zilla-medium">Jobs Created</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey, great solution. Can you explain a little bit? I am having hard times understanding, how this works.